# Jenkins FindBugs OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: jenkins, out-of-memory, permgen

I am running a FindBugs job on a Jenkins server. The exact schedule is `H 6 * * 1-5`. The job itself executes a FindBugs ant task with `jvmargs="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g"`. After finishing, the [FindBugs plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin) collects the XML output. It seems that this plugin causes the following `OutOfMemoryError`.

```
13.08.2013 06:37:08 hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: FindBugs #25 main build action completed: SUCCESS
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Exception in thread "Jenkins cron thread" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen sp
ace
Exception in thread "ConnectorThread:[ajp13-8009]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: P
ermGen space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

So my question is: Where do I need to increase the PermGen space? At the Jenkins server itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really advise you to read [this first](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/I%27m+getting+OutOfMemoryError).

If you conclude after that that you need to increase the permgen for the Jenkins process, doing it will depend on how you installed jenkins (custom install, deb, rpm, pkg, exe...). In that case you will need to tell us about your environment for guidance on how to pass those parameters to your process.